# Minimize norm of a polynomial on a circle

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Let $P=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kX^k$ ba a polynomial of degree $n \gt 0$, and let
$r\gt 0$. Suppose that $P$ is not the monomial $a_nX^n$, in other words
there is at least an $i<n$ such that $a_i\neq 0$. Denote by $C$ the 
circle $\big\lbrace z \ \big| \ |z|=r\big\rbrace$. Clearly,
the continuous function $|P|$ attains a minimum value (let us denote it
by $\mu$) on the compact set $C$. Let $M=\big\lbrace z\in C
\ \big| \  |P(z)|=\mu\big\rbrace$.
 How many elements can we have in $M$ ? When $\mu=0$, $M$ contains
 only roots of $P$, so that the maximum cardinality is $n$.

For $l\in[-n,n]$, let us put 
 $$b_l=\sum_{j=-n+{\sf max}(0,-l)}^{n+{\sf min}(0,-l)}
 \bar{a_j}a_{j+l}r^{2j+l}, B(X)=\sum_{l=-n}^{n}b_lX^{l+n}, D(X)=\frac{B(X)}{X^n}
 $$.

Then we have the identity $|P(re^{i\theta})|^2=D(e^{i\theta})$ for any $\theta\in{\mathbb R}$.
 Since $D'(X)=\frac{XB'(X)-B(X)}{X^{n+1}}$, we see that 
 $|M| \leq |M'|$ where $M'=\big\lbrace z \in {\mathbb C} \ \big| \ zB’(z)-B(z)=0, |z|=1
 \big\rbrace$. Remark that $D'$ is zero iff $B$ is a monomial in $X$, iff
 $P$ itself is a monomial in $X$. As the degree of $XB'(X)-B(X)$ is exactly $2n$, we deduce $|M| \leq 2n$.

Note however that we have only counted local extrema here, and the question is about the global extrema. Thus, one expects $|M|$ to be significatively
 lower than the upper bound $2n$. In fact, I conjecture the following :

**Conjecture.** $|M| \leq n$.

I have checked this conjecture on a few random numerical examples.
 Does anyone have an idea about how to prove or find a counterexample to
 this conjecture ?

Comment: There are "trivial" cases: for example, if $P(z)=z^n$ then $M$ is the whole circle.

Comment: @Etienne You say “there are”, plural, but you only gave one example of a trivial case. I don’t see any other.

Comment: As far as polynomials go, $P(z) = c\cdot z^n$ are the only examples where $\lvert P(z)\rvert$ is constant on $C$; If you have $f$ holomorphic on $\{\lvert z\rvert < r\}$, continuous on the closure, with $\lvert f(z)\rvert$ constant on $C$, consider the (scaled) Blaschke product $B$ with the same zeros as $f$ in the disk. $f/B$ is zero-free, with constant modulus on $C$, hence constant, so $f = c\cdot B$. A Blaschke product is a polynomial if and only if it is of the form $B(z) = c\cdot z^k$.

Comment: @Ewan You're right, as Daniel explained...

Comment: It seems that your conjecture is correct: since $\vert P(re^{i\theta})\vert^2$ is a (nonnegative) trigonometric polynomial in $\theta$, it attains a minimum value only at finitely many $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$, unless it is constant.

Comment: @Etienne Ah, I think I see now : the derivative can only have a finite number of zeroes.

Comment: Yes, this is it...

Comment: I believe you should write the discussion up as an answer (crediting the comments) and accept it to close the issue.

Comment: @vonbrand indeed, but there are still some open questions left : my original guess was that, except in the trivial cases, the cardinality of $|S|$ is at most $n$. On the other hand the polynomial yielded by Etienne’s method has degree $2n$, so we must show that it has at most $n$ roots on the circle. I need to think more about this before updating this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was promptly answered as soon as I cross-posted it on MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/159173/minimize-norm-of-a-polynomial-around-a-circle-count-the-solutions?noredirect=1#comment407081_159173